# How to return a null list?

Tags: c#, list, nullreferenceexception

I have a list and I want to check if it's null then handle it properly

```
public List<Entitys.Member> GetALLMembers()
{            
    List<Models.EF_Model.Member> list = new Models.CRUD.Member().Get_AllMemeberRecords();
    //this is null and it throws exception => list
    List<Entitys.Member> ListMember = new List<Entitys.Member>();
    if (list!=null)
    {
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            ListMember.Add(new Entitys.Member()
            {
                //doing sth
            });
        }
    return ListMember;
    }
    else
    {
        return()
    }
}
```

I want to initialize it to something or a string and then in my controller throw a message.

How can I initialize a List in this way?

Comment: "sth" ? what is sth ?

Comment: @BugFinder sth = something

Comment: Well of course you can create list and do stuff with it if you find its null....

Comment: **(1)** `want to initialize it to sth or a string` Decide what you want/need to do before asking how to do it. **(2)** `and then in my controller throw a message` if you mean **throw** as in throwing an exception, then you have to do it before supplying a default value (otherwise you're putting the cart before the horse). If you mean to log a notification (e.g. to a log), you can do that at any point you want to. But again, **decide what it is you want** before trying to build it.

Comment: @BugFinder Well yes,but I have to return something

Comment: So make a new list but dont fill it...

Comment: return an empty list? Or just `null` also?

Comment: Just always return `ListMember`. The caller can check if it is empty.

Comment: You can't initialise a List to a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if list is null. If it is then you can just return an empty List, otherwise create the new list. If it is null, there's no need to add anything to the list. The point of the method is to return all members and if the list is null then there are apparently no members. It would be incorrect to return anything other than an empty list or maybe even null.

```
public List<Entitys.Member> GetALLMembers()
{            
    List<Models.EF_Model.Member> list = new Models.CRUD.Member().Get_AllMemeberRecords();
    if (list != null)
        return list.Select(l => new Entitys.Member()).ToList();
    else
        return new List<Entitys.Member>();
}
```